# Django ORM Count by Related Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    pass

class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    members = models.ManyToManyField("main.Profile", through='main.TeamMember')

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile')
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So, I try to order teams by count of profiles with a certain role, and I had a query, which doesn't work:

```
Team.objects.filter(members__role='ExampleRole').annotate(example_role_count=Count('members')).order_by('example_role_count')
```

It raises the following Exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: role
```

because role is a TeamMember field, not Profile. So, how can I achieve ordering by count of members with a specified role?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found a solution (works only in Django >= 1.11)

```
queryset = Team.objects.annotate(example_role_count=Subquery(TeamMember.objects.filter(role='example_role', team=OuterRef('pk')).values('team').annotate(cnt=Count('pk')).values('cnt'), output_field=IntegerField())).order_by('-example_role_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the queryset by 'through' model field and then want to order the result set based on related field count,

```
from django.db.models import Count

# descending order
Team.objects.filter(teammember__role='ExampleRole').annotate(example_role_count=Count('members')).order_by('-example_role_count')
```